# Download files using Python-Telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I was trying to download the file send by the user via telegram app using python script, I am using the Python-telegram-bot library, I was not able to download the file, below is my code.

```
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, MessageHandler, filters

BOT_TOKEN = '...'

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def downloader(bot, update, context):
    logger.info(update.message.document.file_name)
    logger.info(update.message.document.file_id)
    context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download()

    # writing to a custom file
    with open("custom/file.doc", 'wb') as f:
        context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download(out=f)

application = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()

# on different commands - answer in Telegram
application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Document.ALL, downloader))

# Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
application.run_polling()
```

**Edited (Working code)**:

After going through the telegram-bot document as suggested by @CallMeStag, below code is working, I have few more doubts

1. I am able to download file, only if the sender types the command(any text with slash-"/") while sending file.

[image: File sent with command]

2. I am unable to download multiple files, sent by user.
3. It is more appreciated, if anyone can edit my code and make it work for multiple file.

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, MessageHandler, filters, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

BOT_TOKEN = '.....'

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def downloader(update, context):
    # Download file
    fileName = update.message.document.file_name
    new_file = await update.message.effective_attachment.get_file()
    await new_file.download_to_drive(fileName)

    # Acknowledge file received
    await update.message.reply_text(f"{fileName} saved successfully")

    # Send the file
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    file_id = '20221222-.pptx'
    await context.bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=file_id)

application = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()

# on different commands - answer in Telegram
application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.ALL, downloader))

# Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
application.run_polling()
```

Comment: Does the `downloader` function not download a file?

Comment: Yes, the downloader function is not able to download the file, I am also not getting any response from log info (Which is located with in the downloader function)

Comment: Is the function executed at all?

Comment: No, the downloader function is not executed, even after the file received from user in the telegram group.

Comment: Is the line with `add_handler` executed?

Comment: I doubt add_handler is working, I also suspect the filter.Document.ALL might be not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handler callbacks accept exactly 2 positional arguments, not three. See the docs of [`MessageHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0b0/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html#telegram.ext.MessageHandler.params.callback) for more info.

Moreover, keep in mind that in the recent versions, the methods of [`telegram.File`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0b0/telegram.file.html#telegram.File) have been renamed. In particular, there is now `File.download_to_memory` and `File.download_to_drive`, bot no `File.download` anymore.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Thank you, I have updated working code above, Please can you post the edited code and let us know how multiple file can be downloaded.

Comment: As your original question was answered, I recommend to open a new question for your follow-up questions. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
def start_function(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Hello there! I'm AskPython Bot.")
 
 
def help_function(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
        """
    Available commands:
 
    /start : Starts up the bot
    /help : Help topics
    /about : About text
    /askpython : Go to AskPython Offical Website
    /custom : Other custom commands 
 
    """
    )
 
 
def about_function(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("I am a bot and also a Python Genie.")
 
 
def ask_python_function(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("AskPython Website: https://www.askpython.com/")
 
 
def custom_function(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).